# Where can I find original constituents of compound words?

Tags: vocabulary

English compound words are clear in the sense that one can understand their constituents:

- notebook
- dinner table
- long-term

As you can see, there are at least three types of compound words in English: closed, open, hyphenated

However, Korean compound words are all closed and shortened. The irrelevant hanja's or morphemes are cut out and it is hard to 'reverse engineer' the original constituents even looking at the hanja dictionary.

An example: 전항 (이전 항목).

So, where can I find original constituents of compound words?

Comment: You need to know the Hanja equivalents for most such constituents

Comment: yes, I know that. but the problem is as you can see, the original words are concatenated and without the original words, it is hard to "reverse engineer" the constituents.

Comment: 전  is not an abbreviation of 이전, 전 itself means previous, similar for 항

Comment: yes I know that too :))) but I am sure 전항 is abbreviation for 이전 항목. So I want to find the mapping: 전항 --> 이전 항목

Comment: If you are good at Korean, 고려대학교 한국어대사전(available at naver dictionary) would be good choice. I found '전항', and it gave me 형태(shape) : [前項].

Comment: thanks I found this very helpful, but still could not find the compound words. Perhaps, 전항 is not a good example

Comment: Well, English does have many difficult compounds: NASA, FBI, Brexit, albeit, awry, infrared, de facto, et cetera.  Not many English speakers would know that _helicopter_ is made of _helico-_ + _-pter_ "spiral wings".

Comment: fair enough. But still, for a Korean learner, it is much easier to memorize the word if the constituents are known. That is the reason why I got so interested in this matter ~~

Comment: 以前 項目 (이전 항목) is not the constituent of 前項. It is just, as you called in your other question, an "의미" - one way to describe the word. Why isn't a native Korean "의미", like you get in most dictionaries, sufficient for this purpose?

Comment: what you said is probably right. But my fault is that maybe I have chosen the wrong example. Anyways the question, as I see it a valid one, and I will come up with a better example

Comment: "Korean compound words are all closed and shortened," you mentioned, but it is not true. Think about 손가방 (a handbag, handbags; 손 (hand, hands) + 가방 (bag)), 눈물 (tears; 눈 (eye, eyes) + 물 (water)), 비옷 (a raincoat, raincoats; 비 (rain) + 옷 (clothes)), etc. These are easy to understand and do not have Hanja. 북반구 (北半球; 북 (north, northern) + 반구 (hemisphere)) and 대포알 (대포 (cannon(s), artillery) + 알 (egg(s), ball(s))) have Hanja but there is no shortening.

Comment: And isn't "dinner table" a phrase (a group of words not a word)? Such phrases can be found in Korean, too. 기후 요소 (氣候要素), 장마 전선 (장마前線), 대류 불안정 (對流不安定), 식이 요법 (食餌療法), 수산 가공업 (水産加工業), 학업 성적 (學業成績), ... There are many examples in the standard dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a bad grasp on the concept.

전항 is not composed of 이전 + 항목. It is simply a compound word of two words 전(前) and 항(項). 전 means roughly the same thing as 이전, and 항 means roughly the same thing as 항목.

이전 "before now" is also a compound word made out of 이(以) "boundary in time or space" and 전(前) "front, before".  항목 is also a compound word made out of 항(項) "item" and 목(目) "item".

Comment: I think 전항 was not a good example. How about  만기 (만료 기간, expiry, maturity (day)), does it qualify for a compound word?

Comment: @eugen 만기(滿期) is composed of 만(滿) "to complete" and 기(期) "period". It is not comprised of 만료 and 기한, they just share the same chinese character so their meanings are similar.

Comment: I see. I will try to find a better example then

Comment: @eugen maybe, let's rethink this problem. I suggest treating single syllables of *hanjaeo* as [bound morphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_and_free_morphemes). To give an English example, the word *antecedent* is not made up of the words *anterior* and *succeed*; instead their Latin roots are *ante* and *cēdō*, which are also part of the English words *anterior* and *succeed*.